# Revise Reputation League Text on Users page

Tags: feature-request, reputation-leagues, users-page

On the [users page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/), there is the following text:

> weekly / monthly / quarterly reputation leagues

However, the entire text is one link to the [weekly league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta-stackoverflow).

I suggest that it be changed either to four separate links (adding yearly), or that it just display `reputation leagues` if only one link is desired. After all, when I click `monthly`, I expect to go straight to the monthly page, so either it should take me there or the `monthly` text should be removed.

Answer (score -2):

I don't agree -- the whole point of the reputation leagues is to show **time intervals** -- something we don't do at all. So we want to really emphasize that aspect of it.

We also want to drive people to the weekly leagues since those are the ones they actually have the best chance of doing well in.

Comment: Then maybe revise it to say `weekly reputation leagues`? The words `monthly` and `quarterly` are misleading there.